# What is the easiest way to change the polarity of a transistor based simple amplifier?

Tags: transistors, amplifier

I would like to amplify signals from a silicon photomultiplier, which is an array of many small avalanche photodiodes (APDs). When one or a few APDs get hit by a photon, a small current will flow through a load resistor. The voltage change over that load resistor will be amplified by an op-amp based voltage pre-amp. The amplified signal is very narrow (in the order of 1 us). I then use a few RC integrators to stretch the signal to ~ 100 us, which reduces the height of the signal.

I want to use another amplifier shown below to re-amplify the stretched signal. The color in the diagram doesn't matter. All cross wires are connected. The right most C and R are inside a sound card and are not part of the amplifier. But I do want to feed the amplified, stretched signal to a sound card for data recording. The sound card sampling frequency is too low to handle the original narrow signal. That's why I need to stretch and amplify the original signal coming out of a voltage pre-amp.

[image]

The problem is that the voltage change of the load resistor is positive, it is still positive after the pre-amp, while the amplifier shown here seems only to work for a negative input pulse. What's the easiest modification to make it work for positive input? I'd like to keep the 5V input as it is easy to get from a USB connection. If possible I also want to keep the same transistor in the design. Adding more transistors in the design is fine.

Comment: What's with all the red and green annotations?

Comment: What is the input signal coming from?

Comment: Could you afford to add one more gain stage between the gain stage and the source follower? That will give the additional inversion but your overall gain will increase.

Comment: Is your input signal a current pulse already?

Comment: what is the signal you want to amplify, exactly? You say "pulse", but what exactly does that mean? For what kind of output do you want to amplify? The input signal and the desired output define what your amplifier needs to do, so you will have to tell us. "I want to amplify" is not enough – it's probably easiest if you could tell us what connects to the input and what to the output, precisely.

Comment: Very poor circuit diagram; some junctions have dots and others don't. I suggest you ditch the circuit and explain what you are trying to achieve. Now you might think I'm being petty mentioning the dots but, in my long experience of designs, someone who doesn't take care to make a decent schematic probably cares not too much about making it work reliably or effectively.

Comment: To second Andy: Someone who has no dot / small dot / large dot and lines of different widths mixed in their circuit diagram probably just badly copied together the schematic from somewhere else. That sadly usually comes with a lack of understanding and a desire to build a website that generates ad revenue as quickly as possible. Now this looks like someone tried to build a special-use case (some already pre-amplified pulse signal going in here?) amplifier and didn't take signal quality too serious. You're probably better off just replacing it with something that actually fits your use case.

Comment: I updated my original question to provide a context and tried to answer all your questions in the comments all together. Please let me know if more clarification is needed.

Comment: you already know that an Opamp can be used for this – use an opamp amplifier. Opamps were invited **exactly** for this.

Comment: @MarcusMüller What's the advantage of an op-amp based design over this one?

Comment: the fact that building an opamp amplifier is trivial and building a transistor amplifier, as demonstrated by this very post, is not? In the very *best* case, you build your transistor amplifier to work as well as an opamp-based linear amplifier within your signal range. That is literally the goal! Start with an opamp, and you get the end goal as starting point.

Comment: From what you wrote, it seems your signal is already voltage amplifier. If so, why are using shunt feedback at the input of this discrete amplifier; instead, you want the amplifier to have a large input impedance

Comment: @ErnestoG, I guess R4 and R5 is used to provide a positive input to the last transistor. From what you wrote, I guess you'd suggest to switch to an op-amp based design as well?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I thought this discrete amplifier is simple enough to modify...

Comment: The point of opamps is that they make a complicated thing (matching the usage of a couple transistors to amplify the signal you want) easy. So, this is 100% a use case for an opamp. Tuning a two-transistor circuit to work with exactly your working point is not that easy.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks a lot for the advice!

Comment: Please edit the question to make it clear whether you care about pulse amplitude or not. Because if you don’t care about absolute amplitude, then this whole thing reduces to one or two op-amps as an AC amplifier, a comparator, and a one-shot. Pulse lengthening is easy in digital domain. Anyway, why do you need those pulses to be 100us long? Are they supposed to go to a speaker? I’d only design this out of discrete transistors as some nod towards the old times. It’d take quite a bit more work than an op-amp circuit that most can draw on a napkin and it will work first try.

Comment: After you edit the question making it clear what the application is, then an answer with a simple to implement circuit becomes easy. Discrete transistors are only “easy” in introductory level homework assignments. There are a lot of websites that offer impractical circuits that were never built or that perform needlessly poorly given their complexity.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica, I'd like to use cheap ADC to record the signal. Cheap ADCs don't have very high sampling rate. That's why I want to lengthen the pulse before sending it to an ADC. I don't care about absolute amplitude, I do care about signal to noise ratio.